# how to add single quotes in data factory dynamics experssion

Tags: api, azure-data-factory

below is my API

https://abc/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$apply=filter((_ownerid_value ne null) and (owningteam/teamtype eq 0 and contains(owningteam%2fname, 'xyz')))/aggregate($count as values)

and i'm trying add paramters to  it(linkedservice().entityname) ,so in dynamic content i have made the following changes , but it is giving error at 'xyz'.

@concat('https://abc.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/',linkedService().entityname,'?$apply=filter((_ownerid_value ne null) and (owningteam/teamtype eq 0 and contains(owningteam%2fname,',''','xyz',''',')))/aggregate($count as values)')

```
@concat('https://abc.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/',linkedService().entityname,'?$apply=filter((_ownerid_value ne null) and (owningteam/teamtype eq 0 and contains(owningteam%2fname,',''','xyz',''',')))/aggregate($count as values)')
```

Answer (score 0):

this way it worked for me

@{concat('data/v9.0/',linkedService().Entityname,'?$apply=filter((_ownerid_value',' ','ne',' ','null)',' ','and',' ','(owningteam/teamtype',' ','eq',' ','0',' ','and',' ','contains(owningteam%2fname,','''','xez','''',')',')',')','/aggregate($count',' ','as',' ','PROD)')}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use two single quotes **`''`** in the expression to get the string value with a single quote **`'`** in the result.

```
@concat('https://abc/api/data/v9.1/',pipeline().parameters.entityname,'?$apply=filter((_ownerid_value ne null) and (owningteam/teamtype eq 0 and contains(owningteam%2fname, ''xyz'')))/aggregate($count as values)')
```

[image]

Results:

[image]